# Is this answer true?

Tags: special-functions, difference-equations

I was using *Mathematica* to get the series solution for `Legendre` equation. But when I get the recurrence relation and use `RSolve`:

```
RSolve[Subscript[a, n + 2] == ((n - l) (n + l + 1))/((1 + n) (2 + n)) Subscript[a, n], 
   Subscript[a, n], n] // FullSimplify // TraditionalForm
```

(where `l` and `n` are both non-negative)

Just for calculating the coefficient of the series,
I only find the solution is strange:

> {{Subscript[a, n]->Γ(1/2 (-l+n))/Γ(-(l/2)) (2^n (Subscript[c, 2] (-1)^n+Subscript[c, 1])  Γ(1/2 (l+n+1)))/(Γ(n+1)  Γ(1/2 (l+1)))}}

I was confused that when `l` and `n` are even and `n` < `l`,the answer will be `ComplexInfinity`. But it is so counter-intuitive！

Comment: What happens after applying `FullSimplify[]`?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use this form (subscripts removed because they're messy):

```
FullSimplify[RSolve[a[n + 2] == ((n + k + 1) (n + k) - 
 l (l + 1))/((n + k + 1) (n + k + 2)) a[n], a[n], n]]

(* you should get...*)
result = (2^n (C[1]+(-1)^n C[2])Gamma[1+k]Gamma[1/2 (k-l+n)]Gamma[
 1/2 (1+k+l+n)])/(Gamma[(k-l)/2] Gamma[1/2 (1+k+l)]Gamma[1+k+n])
```

Using this, you can now set k=0 to get the even half of the coefficients, and k=1 to get the odd half. This is the reason you were getting weird results, because you were trying to calculate the other half of coefficients from the wrong recurrence relation. NOTE: there are generated parameters C[1], C[2] because you haven't got specific initial conditions.

Now I think you can do:

```
evenCoeff = Table[FullSimplify[result /. {k -> 0}], {n, 0, 6, 2}]
oddCoeff = Table[FullSimplify[result /. {k -> 1}], {n, 0, 6, 2}]
```

Look at equations (4.13) in [this text](http://www.hep.ucl.ac.uk/~cw/MATHS/webnd.pdf) for more. I'm afraid I've never covered the Legendre equation or its polynomials so I'm only going on what I've read. The page on [mathworld.wolfram.com](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDifferentialEquation.html) also says this which is suggestive of you get undefined results if you try to look for the even coefficients with the odd reccurence relation and vice versa:

> If l is an even integer, the series y_1(x) reduces to a polynomial of
>   degree l with only even powers of x and the series y_2(x) diverges. If
>   l is an odd integer, the series y_2(x) reduces to a polynomial of
>   degree l with only odd powers of x and the series y_1(x) diverges.

Comment: Yes,I just think that Gamma may appear oddly when n is not necessary positive.

Comment: I'm still not sure about the correctness of my answer but I think that's approximately the reason why it was giving complex infinity. Gamma returns complex infinity on all non-positive integers as well. You could try `FullSimplify[... , Element[n|l,Integers]&&n>0&&l>0]` see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Note function [`LegendreP`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendreP.html) gives normalized orthogonal polynomials.

Approaching your recursion by nesting can reproduce these (though not proving where coefficients vanish). So for illustrative purposes (changing l to j):

```
f[n_, j_] := - (j + n + 1) (j - n)/((n + 1) (n + 2));
es[a_, j_, n_] := 
 First@Nest[{f[#[[2]], j] #[[1]], #[[2]] + 2} &, {a, 0}, n/2]
os[a_, j_, n_] := 
  First@Nest[{f[#[[2]], j] #[[1]], #[[2]] + 2} &, {a, 1}, Floor[n/2]];
esol[x_, j_?EvenQ] := (es[1, j, #] & /@ Range[0, 2 j, 2]).Table[
    x^(2 k), {k, 0, j}];
osol[x_, j_?OddQ] := (os[1, j, #] & /@ Range[1, 2 j + 1, 2]).Table[
    x^(2 k + 1), {k, 0, j}];
lp[n_?OddQ, x] := With[{c = osol[1, n]}, Expand[osol[x, n]/c]]
lp[n_?EvenQ, x] := With[{c = esol[1, n]}, Expand[esol[x, n]/c]]
```

e.g

```
Grid[{Expand@LegendreP[#, x], lp[#, x]} & /@ Range[8], Frame -> All]
```

[image]